# UIScrollView stops working when changing view

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I'm new to Xcode, and now I'm getting really frustrated about `UIScrollView`. I succeeded
in creating a ScrollView, and it worked fine with content and everything. But then I wanted to creat a new ViewController, with its own scrollview, and its own content! But that won't work!

Here is my problem:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LktaCZhBu4E&feature=youtu.be

I've uploaded the video to show what the problem looks like!

Here is my viewController.m :

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  EHN Biler
//
//  Created by Daniel Høi-Nielsen on 13/11/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 EHN Graphis. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

[scroller setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 800)];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
[scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 800)];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

[scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
[scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 8000)];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

And here is the viewController.h:

```
//
//  ViewController.h
//  EHN Biler
//
//  Created by Daniel Høi-Nielsen on 13/11/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 EHN Graphis. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;
}

@property(nonatomic) BOOL canCancelContentTouches;

@end
```

I guess I need some code to make this work, so I really hope someone can help me! I've been searching all over to find the answer! And please remember I'm new to this, so please be educational.

Comment: BTW... When I run it on 3,5 display it works just fine! The problem happens when i run it on 4 inch display/iphone 5! :(

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YTzPpTayfhE&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 0):

If you created a scrollView from nib you have to uncheck the  **Use Autolayout** from there:

- Go to your nib.
- Select your view.
- Go to utility window of nib.
- Select First tab form left of utility window.
- UNCHECK Autolayout.